# My new Date returns Invalid Date when using timezone ON FIREFOX

Tags: javascript

I'm using a function to transform my date to ISO, when using it on Chrome, the function works fine, but when using it on Firefox I get Invalid Date.

Can I use something else to specify my timezone?

```js
const date = new Date("2020-04-22" + "GMT-0300").toISOString().substr(0, 10);

/** Output
 * Chrome: 2020-04-22
 * Firefox: Invalid Date
 */
console.log(date);
```

Comment: `GMT-0300` doesn't look like a timezone designator to me. Did you mean `T00:00:00-03:00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slashes - tested in FX and Chrome

NOTE: Why is the timezone important for you for a DATE? If you want the date to be the 21st somewhere, you need 00:00:00. But if you want the date to be the 22nd for everyone, you need 14:00 or 15:00 since the biggest time zone difference is 12 or something

```js
let date = new Date("2020/04/22 GMT-0300"); // yes this IS picked up by the browser
console.log(date)
date = date.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
console.log(date)

/** Output
 * Chrome: 2020-04-22
 * Firefox: 2020-04-22
 */

// Better string: NOte the 15:00 to make sure it stays on the date

date = new Date("2020-04-22T15:00:00.000-03:00");
console.log(date)
date = date.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
console.log(date)
```

Comment: I don't know about the downvote, it seems to work for me, I didn't get what 15:00:00.000-03:00 means, what does 15 stand for?

Comment: 3pm - to make sure it’s the same date anywhere

Comment: @mplungjan what's so special about 3pm?

Comment: but that way I would need to keep track of the time at all times?